# Magento2: Create a new order from Admin panel for particular customer

Tags: magento2, product, orders, shopping-cart

Create a new order from Admin panel for a particular customer. Magento default functionality is not working

When I add a new product and update to the shopping cart option then page refresh but the product does not add.

[image]

Comment: Can you list down the steps in more detail?

Comment: Can you share a chat link...so we can discuss in detail.

Comment: 1) Which product already in cart. It is not moving in items ordered.

Comment: 2) I have added 1 product in items ordered then I select move to shopping cart drop-down option under action then I click on update button product does not add in the shopping cart. @MohitKumarArora

Comment: any error into console or log file?

Comment: No errors in console and log files. @DhirenVasoya

Comment: Any solution for this? I am getting the same issue